# Openshift pod runnning with user id not matching with user in Dockerfile

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, operator-sdk

We had "default" user in Dockerfile and entrypoint shell script , which need to be execute during run time. When we deployed this into Openshift cluster(4.6), pod is having different user and due to this entrypoint shell script is failing hence application is not coming up. Request you to  suggest how to execute those shell scripts even with user in POD

Comment: What is this default user that you are referring too? Can you provide more details? Quick guess based on what you said would to use openshift [security context constraints](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html).

Answer (score 0):

Openshift provides security context constraints (SCC) to control permissions for pods. With them you are able to to control permissions/actions that a pod or collection of containers can perform and what resources they can access.
Couple of things that SCCs allow an administrator to control:

> - Whether a pod can run privileged containers.
> - The SELinux context of the container.
> - The container user ID.
> - The allocation of an  `FSGroup`  that owns the pod’s volumes.
> - The configuration of allowable supplemental groups.
> - Whether a container requires the use of a read only root file system.
> - The usage of volume types.

SCCs are composed of settings and strategies that control the security features a pod has access to. If I understood correctly your questions you want to check the `RunAsUser` strategies:

1. `MustRunAs`  - Requires a  `runAsUser`  to be configured. Uses the configured  `runAsUser`  as the default. Validates against the configured  `runAsUser`.
2. `MustRunAsRange`  - Requires minimum and maximum values to be defined if not using pre-allocated values. Uses the minimum as the default. Validates against the entire allowable range.
3. `MustRunAsNonRoot`  - Requires that the pod be submitted with a non-zero  `runAsUser`  or have the  `USER`  directive defined in the image. No default provided.
4. `RunAsAny`  - No default provided. Allows any  `runAsUser`  to be specified.

For more please have a look at the [official openshift docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html).